# How to set input type in TextField in Mui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want the textfield to only allow integer inputs:

```html
<TextField value={inputs.length} name="length" required label="Enter length" color="secondary" variant="filled" onChange={handleChange} size="small" focused sx={{input: { color: "whitesmoke",}}} style={{ marginTop: "0.5em", marginRight: "0.5em", marginLeft: "0.5em"}}/>
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The API docs say https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input/ can accept a `type` attribute that is a valid HTML5 attribute

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_%3Cinput%3E_types

In your case you want to use `number`